# jQuery draggable multiple elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Please how can I move the two red div (`.drag_sim`) with the green div (`.drag_multi`).
The red div are also draggable.

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9sNEK/14/

**HTML**

```
<div class="drag_multi"></div>

<div class="pdrag" id="pdrag1">
    <div class="drag_sim"></div>
</div>

<div class="pdrag" id="pdrag2">
    <div class="drag_sim"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.drag_multi').draggable();
$('.drag_sim').draggable();
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

remove the bellow css part and try

```
.drag_multi, .pdrag, .drag_sim{
  position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to drag red one and green one separately or What ? i'm confusing on what are you asking

Comment: I can see those two can drag without a problem.when you used position:absolute; the green one is going inside the pdrag div

Comment: I want when I drag the green div the two red div is dragging also